# Checking For Next Line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, for-loop

I am attempting to loop over a series of text files I have and I want to do so by checking the value of the next line. The input from the text file looks like:

```
Person1
(COUNT)|key
1|************

Person2
(COUNT)|key

// and so on
```

Some people may have a key and others may not. I am trying to write a loop that checks for at least 3 consecutive lines (people with keys) before a space like the `Person1` example where each line begins with a character and I want to print only those cases.

My current loop looks like this:

```
for line in input:
    if re.match(r'\S', line):
        line1 = line
        print(line1)
        if re.match(r'\S', input.next()):
            line2 = line
            print(line2)
            if re.match(r'\S', input.next()):
                line3 = line
                print(line3)
```

However, I cannot seem to get this loop correct. It seems to be printing the Person three times and only sometimes printing the key. Looking for any guidance here available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to get the current index and be able to check the next lines too. You'll need to beware the case when you reach the end of the file though.

```
for i, line in enumerate(input):
   if i == len(input) - 2:
       break
   next_line = line[i+1]
```

Comment: Just use an if statement for that end case, something along the lines of `if i == len(line): break`.